# Are there any board game appropriate to examine the performance of multiple agents that cooperate both inter-group and intra-group?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, multi-agent-systems

I want to find out scenarios that useful to examine the performance of intra-group and inter-group cooperation in MARL. 
Specifically, I prefer a board game (like sudoku) that is suitable for the cooperation evaluation.

But there are some differences between the requirements and the go like game. Every grid on the board should be treated as an agent. They are designed to form a situation with the local utility and global utility.

Take the sudoku as an example, every grid should choose an appropriate value to reach the sudoku solution.

Due to my non-familiarity with traditional MARL scenarios, it will be a great help for showing me some keywords or lists.

Comment: Hi Jarvis and welcome to AI SE! I think it would be better if you defined more precisely what you mean by "matrix game". Are you looking for board games where you can test MARL systems/algorithms?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I will modify the problem description. Yes! I am looking for some kinds of board games. But there is still some difference between that and the go like games. The detailed description I would add to the problem descriptions.